# How to commit every iteration within a loop while inserting batches into table

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, offset, bulkinsert

I wrote a stored procedure to select chunks of records from one large table and insert into another table by batches. It doesn't seem to insert records every iteration but rather insert all batches all at once at the end. Is there a way to actually insert records to the destination table each iteration?

This is what my function looks like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cms.load_records_from_staging_batch(batch_size int)
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$body$
DECLARE 
  row_cnt int;
  oset int;
  counter int;
BEGIN
  row_cnt := (select count(*)::int from cost_settlements_stg);
  raise notice 'Total % rows in cost_settlements_stg', row_cnt;
  oset := 0;
  while oset <= row_cnt loop
    insert into cms.cost_settlements 
      (item_text
      , item_description)
      select item_text
            , item_description
      from cms.cost_settlements_stg limit batch_size offset oset
    on conflict on constraint cost_settlements_unique_key 
    do nothing;
    
    oset := oset + batch_size;
    counter := counter + 1;
    raise notice 'Batch loaded %', counter';
  end loop;
END;
```

Comment: Committing once at the end of the transaction is typically faster than committing frequently in a loop (and doing bulk operations **without** a loop is also typically faster than with a loop). But if you really want to make that slower, use a stored procedure, then you can issue a `commit` inside the loop

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I used to not have the loop. 10M rows got inserted within 9 minutes. Today it is extremely slow. That's why I am using the loop. I don't know if commiting inserts of many chunks all at once  is essentially the same as comminting all records. THe job is still running, I hope it doesn't get stuck at the end.

Comment: If you commit within the loop and the process fails then you will have a partial load that will need to be recovered.  Generally speaking doing commits in the body of a procedure is not good, though there can be a case made for it.

Answer (score 0):

The rows are inserted as you go, it is only that they are invisible until the end of the transaction.

Do all the inserts in a single transaction and in a single statement, that will be fast:

```
INSERT INTO cms.cost_settlements (item_text, item_description)
SELECT item_text, item_description
FROM cms.cost_settlements_stg
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT cost_settlements_unique_key DO NOTHING;
```